# VBA Returning Values from Split String

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to return and define the split values of a defined string. (in vba) The delimiter of the cell is "@".

Here is an example: "Element1@Element2@Element3@Element4"

I have been successful in doing this when it is only "Element1@Element2" using the following code:

```
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Linerange.Value

Dim Element1 As String
Dim Element2 As String

Element1 = Left(Linerange.Value, InStr(1, Linerange.Value, "@") - 2)
Element2 = Right(Linerange.Value, Len(Linerange.Value) - InStr(1, Linerange.Value, "@") - 1)
```

Any idea how to approach this and define values for Element3 and Element4?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the [Split Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`Split` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) on your value:

```
Dim elements, ele  '' Declared implicitly as Variant type

elements = Split(Linerange.Value, "@")
For Each ele in elements
    Debug.Print ele
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim vSplit As Variant
vSplit=Split(Linerange.Value,"@")
```

You then have an array of `vSplit()`